# How to get only plain text (String) in response of Ajax url?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am fairly new to Ajax. I am using Ajax to fill dropdown after selecting a value from different dropdown in HTML. The problem is that, I am getting my required output plus HTML format.

The javascript code is -

```
    function showHint(str)
{  
//  alert("Ajax - " + str);

var xmlhttp;
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


  xmlhttp.open("GET","AjaxCall.jsp?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    { 
     alert("xmlhttp.responseText - " +  xmlhttp.responseText  ); 
    }
  }


}
```

Here in xmlhttp.responseText (alert), I am getting the output -

[image]

I need the output only -

D1&&&D2&&&D3&&&D4

I do not want this extra HTML code.

My AjaxCall.jsp is -

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <%@ page import="com.Search.Struts2.AccessCheckComponent"%>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*"%> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setContentType("text/plain");

%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%

System.out.println("-------------------jsp -------------- " );  

String cpmt = request.getParameter("q");
System.out.println("cpmt -!!Ajax - jsp !! " + cpmt);    

String deckStr = AccessCheckComponent.CheckCompartmentDeckRelationship(cpmt);
System.out.println("deckList -!!Ajax - jsp !! " + deckStr); 

  response.getWriter().write(deckStr.toString());  

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the HTML since you're JSP sends it back in the response. To fix that, you need to set the `contentType` of the page to `text/plain` and remove all the HTML elements from the JSP (i.e. `<!DOCTYPE...>`, `<html>` and everything. Just write `D1&&&D2&&&D3&&&D4` to the output.

A cleaner solution would be to write a simple `Servlet`. That way, you can avoid all the JSP overhead.

Comment: Would be nice to see that example `Servlet`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the deckStr.toString() just remove the other extra code on you jsp, like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <%@ page import="com.Search.Struts2.AccessCheckComponent"%>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*"%> 

<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setContentType("text/plain");

System.out.println("-------------------jsp -------------- " );  

String cpmt = request.getParameter("q");
System.out.println("cpmt -!!Ajax - jsp !! " + cpmt);    

String deckStr = AccessCheckComponent.CheckCompartmentDeckRelationship(cpmt);
System.out.println("deckList -!!Ajax - jsp !! " + deckStr); 

  response.getWriter().write(deckStr.toString());  

%>
```

And this will display for you only the data you need.